# multidimensional Array same value remove array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello everyone i'm struggling with a issue and couldn't really find my answer on the web.
Maybe i made a mistake than sorry but the answers i found where not exactly where i where searching for.

Here is my problem

```
  ["acList"]=>
  array(356) {
    [0]=>
    array(36) {
      ["Id"]=>
      int(434367)
      ["Rcvr"]=>
      int(154)
      ["HasSig"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["Sig"]=>
      int(19)
      ["Icao"]=>
      string(6) "06A0BF"
      ["Bad"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["Reg"]=>
      string(6) "A7-BDA"
      ["FSeen"]=>
      string(21) "/Date(1509481499558)/"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(43) {
      ["Id"]=>
      int(3753696)
      ["Rcvr"]=>
      int(149)
      ["HasSig"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["Sig"]=>
      int(23)
      ["Icao"]=>
      string(6) "3946E0"
      ["Bad"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["Reg"]=>
      string(6) "A7-BDA"
      ["FSeen"]=>
      string(21) "/Date(1509481476453)/"
    }
```

I want that when "Reg" is the same that he removes only one of the same arrays (if possible based on FSeen).

I tried to make new array and combine them and i tried array_unique but that is not doing what i want sadly.

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not going to be the most efficient way, or great for large data sets, but this could work:

```
$aArray = array(array('id' => 1), array('id' => 2), array('id' => 1));

// create a tmp array to hold values we want to check
$aTmpArray = array();

// loop over the array
foreach ($aArray as $iPos => $aItem) {

    if(!isset($aTmpArray[$aItem['id']])){
        // if the item doesnt exist in tmp array, add it    
        $aTmpArray[$aItem['id']] = null;
    }else{
        // if the item exists, remove this entry from aArray
        unset($aArray[$iPos]);
    }
}

// set for gc
$aTmpArray = null;
```

It will preserve the first result and remove any subqiquent duplicates/occurances of `id`.